# copying activex controls along with the macros

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to copy an ActiveX control to a different worksheet along with the macro associated with it?

Thanks

Comment: only by explicitly writing the same code to the new sheet module. much simpler to use forms controls instead

Comment: can form controls be copied along with the macro assigned?

Comment: form controls are assigned macros in normal modules so you don't need to copy the code-unless you meant a worksheet in a different workbook?

Comment: nope i meant copying in the worksheet of the same workbook but i want to do it through code.

Comment: that's ok then-if you simply copy the sheet, the assigned macro already exists and you don't need to do anything else

Comment: I don't want to copy the whole sheet.I want to copy a range of cells from one worksheet to another in the same workbook.And that range consists of a control(be it form control or ActiveX) which is to be copied along with the macro assigned to it.

Comment: sorry-I meant button, not sheet!

Comment: But the thing is I'm not able to copy it through code.I searched a lot but didn't get a solution

Comment: see my answer below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code to copy a forms button

```
activesheet.buttons("Button 1").copy
sheets("Sheet1").range("A1").pastespecial
```

or you can create a new one using Buttons.Add

```
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim rTarget As Range
   Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set rTarget = ws.Range("A1")
   With ws.Buttons.Add(Left:=rTarget.Left, Top:=rTarget.Top, Width:=rTarget.Width, Height:=rTarget.Height)
      .Caption = "Some text"
      .OnAction = "Some_macro"
   End With
```

finally, simply copying the range should work unless `application.copyobjectswithcells` is set to False

Answer (score -1):

You can have a commandbutton or combobox from another sheet access the same macro.

Comment: that isn't my question.I want to copy the control and use it